# Swift Array.filter method

Tags: arrays, filter, swift

Swift's filter method is defined as follows:

```
func filter(includeElement: (T) -> Bool) -> [T]
```

Why does filter definition in Swift's array does not have `<T>` in its definition (i.e. filter(...))?

Comment: I think it's implied. This was mentioned at some point during the generics section of this talk: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` is a method of the `Array<T>` class, so `T` is specified at class level and there is no need to replicate that in the method - actually doing that at method level is a mistake:

```
struct Array<T> ... {
    func filter<V>(includeElement: (V) -> Bool) -> [V]
}
```

because `V` is a different type that has no relationship with `T` (unless you set constraints in the generic definition). By mistake I mean `T` and `V` are different types, whereas it could be thought they are the same. Having a generic class with a generic method is perfectly legit though.

Answer (score 0):

it is because this function is defined in an extension to Array struct and the definition of Array has the  in its definition : struct Array

```
class AA<T> {
}

extension AA {
    func something(aThing: T) -> T{
        return aThing
    }
}
```